# Trouble with Apache2 + Passenger + Redmine

Tags: ruby, passenger, redmine

I'm having trouble installing Redmine.  It seems to run just fine under webrick like this:

```
redmine@machine:~$ /usr/bin/ruby1.8 script/rails server webrick -e production
```

Note that this is when I'm logged in as user 'redmine'.

I installed Passenger (v3.0.17) against my existing Apache2 installation and use a /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

My virtual host conf is very simple too:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@machine.com
    ServerName redmine.machine.com

    RailsEnv production

    DocumentRoot /home/redmine/redmine-2.1/public

    <Directory /home/redmine/redmine-2.1/public>
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run this, I get an error "no such file to load -- bundler".  However, notice:

```
redmine@machine:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.2.1)
coderay (1.0.8)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
passenger (3.0.17)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rmagick (2.13.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.11)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
```

All files in `/home/redmine/redmine-2.1` are owned by `redmine:redmine`.  All directories are `0755` and all files are `0644`.

Now, the interesting thing I have noticed when I show processes:

```
redmine@machine:~$ ps -ef | grep "Passenger"
root     21764 21759  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 PassengerWatchdog
root     21773 21764  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 PassengerHelperAgent
root     21775 21773  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 Passenger spawn server                                                                                                                                           
nobody   21778 21764  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
```

I'm certainly no expert in Ruby/Rails/Passenger/Redmine, but I suspect that the fact that Passenger is running as `nobody` instead of `redmine` may be the problem.  According to the docs here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching, Passenger is supposed to switch users to the user who owns /config/environment.ru, so long as that user can read/write logs and is not `root`, correct?  As you can see from the above, that file (the whole app, in fact) is owned by `redmine`, including the logs which are `rwx` for the owner and `redmine` ≠ `root` so, I believe that I've passed the requirements for Passenger to switch to run as `redmine`.

**Three direct questions:**

1. Is this the cause of my inability to run Redmine under Passenger? and**
2. Why is Passenger still running as `nobody`?**
3. In my attempt to fix this, I tried adding the line:

   PassengerDefaultUser www-data

into my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf (as shown above), but it appears to not take affect.  The results of everything is identical with and without that line.  I wouldn't have expected it to fix the problem, but I did expect it to show up as the user that Passenger runs as when I list processes.  It did not.

Other possibly relevant info:

```
redmine@machine:~$ uname -a
Linux machine.****.com 2.6.18-028stab092.1 #1 SMP Wed Jul 20 19:47:12 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

redmine@machine:~$ /usr/bin/ruby1.8 --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundler is the problem.  Do you have any particular reason to use Ruby 1.8.x?  I strongly recommend you to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.x, preferably 1.9.3.  Otherwise, you may want to try a more ancient [bundler version](http://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions) like 0.9.x.  In addition you should downgrade your Rubygems to [1.3.7 or something similar](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update/versions).

In theory Rubygems can be downgraded as follows:

```
sudo gem update --system 1.3.7
```

To install an old bundler version:

```
sudo gem uninstall bundler
sudo gem install bundler --version=0.9.1
```

On several occasions I had to deal with outdated Ruby software, and the best thing to do is to *not* install the system Ruby, but to compile it yourself from sources.  (Not so difficult after all, Ruby is well-packaged.)  And then install the appropriate Rubygems version from sources. Or look at [RVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_Version_Manager), although this can be painful at the beginning.

BTW: I also recommend to use nginx instead of Apache.  The installation is not as well-documented but therefore the configuration files are much simpler.